# Trouble reading pyshark IEEE802.1AD layer dissector values

Tags: python, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

**Background:**
I'm attempting to use the `pyshark` module to dissect a packet containing `triple 802.1AD tags`.  When the layers for the packet are printed, two IEEE8021AD layers are present.

```
 [<ETH Layer>, <IEEE8021AD Layer>, <IEEE8021AD Layer>, <IP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
```

I can see from a Wireshark display of the same packet that the first IEEE8021AD layer contains two VLAN tags and the second layer contains the third tag:

[image: Wireshark packet dissection]

**Question:**

> 1. I can't figure out how to access the 2nd IEEE802.1AD layer using the pyshark module since both layers have the same name.
> 2. In the 1st IEEE802.1AD layer, I can access the DEI and Priority fields of the 1st VLAN, but not the same values for the 2nd VLAN.  The dissector field names for DEI and Priority are the same between the two VLANS that share this layer.

This XML export from Wireshark for this packet shows the two ieee8021ad layers with identical names, as well as the dei and priority dissector fields which have identical names:

```
<proto name="ieee8021ad" showname="IEEE 802.1ad, S-VID: 9, C-VID: 8" size="4" pos="14">
    <field name="ieee8021ad.priority" showname="101. .... .... .... = Priority: 5" size="1" pos="14" show="5" value="5" unmaskedvalue="a0"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.dei" showname="...0 .... .... .... = DEI: 0" size="1" pos="14" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="a0"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.svid" showname=".... 0000 0000 1001 = ID: 9" size="2" pos="14" show="9" value="9" unmaskedvalue="a009"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.priority" showname="100. .... .... .... = Priority: 4" size="1" pos="18" show="4" value="4" unmaskedvalue="80"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.dei" showname="...0 .... .... .... = DEI: 0" size="1" pos="18" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="80"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.cvid" showname=".... 0000 0000 1000 = ID: 8" size="2" pos="18" show="8" value="8" unmaskedvalue="8008"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ah.etype" showname="Type: 802.1ad Provider     Bridge (Q-in-Q) (0x88a8)" size="2" pos="20" show="0x88a8" value="88a8"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="ieee8021ad" showname="IEEE 802.1ad, ID: 7" size="4" pos="22">
    <field name="ieee8021ad.priority" showname="011. .... .... .... = Priority: 3" size="1" pos="22" show="3" value="3" unmaskedvalue="60"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.dei" showname="...0 .... .... .... = DEI: 0" size="1" pos="22" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="60"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ad.id" showname=".... 0000 0000 0111 = ID: 7" size="2" pos="22" show="7" value="7" unmaskedvalue="6007"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ah.etype" showname="Type: ARP (0x0806)" size="2" pos="24" show="0x0806" value="0806"/>
    <field name="ieee8021ah.trailer" showname="Trailer: 000000000000" size="6" pos="54" show="00:00:00:00:00:00" value="000000000000"/>
  </proto>
```

I tried using the pprint module to look a the data structures, but there is no useful output when attempting to print a layer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import pyshark
import pprint

cap = pyshark.FileCapture(filename)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

for i, pkt in enumerate(cap):

    print("----------------- Packet %d --------------------" % i)
    print(pkt.layers)

    print(pkt.ieee8021ad)

    print("        dei      = %s" % pkt.ieee8021ad.dei)
    print("        priority = %s" % pkt.ieee8021ad.priority)
    print("        cvid     = %s" % pkt.ieee8021ad.cvid)
    print("        svid     = %s" % pkt.ieee8021ad.svid)
    #print("        type     = %s" % pkt.ieee8021ad.type)  # 'type'     doesn't exist>
```

Code output:

```
----------------- Packet 1 --------------------
[<ETH Layer>, <IEEE8021AD Layer>, <IEEE8021AD Layer>, <IP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
Layer IEEE8021AD:
    101. .... .... .... = Priority: 5
    ...1 .... .... .... = DEI: 1
    .... 0000 0000 1000 = ID: 8
    Type: 802.1ad Provider Bridge (Q-in-Q) (0x88a8)
    .... 0000 0000 1001 = ID: 9
    100. .... .... .... = Priority: 4
    ...0 .... .... .... = DEI: 0

    dei      = 1   # Drop Eligibility Indicator for VLAN #2
    priority = 5   # Priority for VLAN #2
    cvid     = 8   # ID for VLAN #2
    svid     = 9   # ID for VLAN #1
```

Comment: Question #1:  The 2nd  IEEE8021AD tag can be accessed via the layers list by using a numerical index value:  `pkt.layers[2].priority`.